# How to modify existing model instance in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In Django, I am trying to modify the title of the existing book with id. My views.py file consists of

```
b=Books.objects.filter(book_id__iexact=book)
b.title = "Narnia"
b.save()
```

I am getting error and unable to save the model instance.

Comment: `Books.objects.filter(book_id__iexact=book)` returns a queryset object. You will need to do `Books.objects.get(book_id__iexact=book)` OR `Books.objects.filter(book_id__iexact=book).first()` to return a Books object so you can edit the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `get` method instead of `filter`. When you use filter you are using a queryset object. Instead of using  `Books.objects.filter(book_id__iexact=book)` try using `b=Books.objects.get(book_id__iexact=book)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 methods to update a record.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update

> .get will work for a single object and .filter will work for multiple
> records

```
#1st
b=Books.objects.get(book_id=book)
b.title = 'Foo'
b.save()

#2nd
Books.objects.filter(book_id__iexact=book).update(title='Foo')
```